# Trouble with ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a bit of trouble with this differential equation and could use some help.  I am trying to solve : $x^3 y''-(x^2+xy)y'+(y^2+xy)=0$ with the conditions y(1)=k and y'(1)=k(k+1).

After much manipulation I got it down to the form $x^3/(x+y)^2$ $y''$=$y'+y$.  I am not too sure what to do next and whether this is the correct path.

Comment: no. can you spot where i screwed up?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x = e^t$ and $y = xz$. Then, use the chain rule to get the following:

$y = e^t z$

$y' = z + \dfrac{dz}{dt}$

$y'' = e^{-t}\left(\dfrac{d^2z}{dt^2} + \dfrac{dz}{dt}\right)$

Substitute these into the original equation to get:

$\dfrac{d^2z}{dt^2} - z\dfrac{dz}{dt} = 0$

Integrate this once to get:

$\dfrac{dz}{dt} - \dfrac{1}{2}z^2 = C$

This is easily solved:

$\dfrac{dz}{\tfrac{1}{2}z^2+C} = dt$

$\dfrac{2}{C}\arctan\left(\dfrac{z}{C}\right) = t+D$

$z = C\tan\left(\dfrac{C}{2}(t+D)\right)$

Now undo the substitutions:

$y = Cx\tan\left(\dfrac{C}{2}(\ln x +D)\right)$

Lastly, using the initial conditions gives us $C = k$ and $D = \dfrac{\pi}{2k}$.

Therefore, the solution is $y = kx\tan\left(\dfrac{k}{2}\ln x + \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Let me know if I messed something up here.